# Parsing player_id from an XML file

Tags: php, simplexml

I want to parse title and  `<sd:id type="player">ba294ab5-616a-4c26-8e9a-bc09d3680610`
   using PHP code. I have parsed title attribute from following XML file:

Using following piece of code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);

foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item) {
    $news=(string)$item->title;
}
```

Can you please suggest me a way to parse player_id i.e. `ba294ab5-616a-4c26-8e9a-bc09d3680610` from  `<sd:id type="player">ba294ab5-616a-4c26-8e9a-bc09d3680610</sd:id>`?

Here's the XML String:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <channel>
        <title>SportsData &#187; News</title>
            <item>
            <sd:id type="player">ba294ab5-616a-4c26-8e9a-bc09d3680610</sd:id>
            <title><![CDATA[Rashard Mendenhall: Should be Back Sunday]]></title>
```

Comment: Can you give use this XML feed url?

Comment: sorry i can't provide you XML feed URL.

Comment: It looks like the namespace 'sd' isn't defined anywhere. Did you remove that from the XML string?

Comment: 'sd' is defined under <item>  element

Comment: i accessed <title> element using this code - $xml->channel->item as $item ......((string)$item->title)....now the question is how can i access   <sd:id type="player">ba294ab5-616a-4c26-8e9a-bc09d3680610</sd:id>   to parse player_id  i.e.   ba294ab5-616a-4c26-8e9a-bc09d3680610

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely simplest way in this case is use regular expression (which you can modify if sd:id tag can have more formats). But this works only for loading list of user-id, without link to any other data from XML node. However it will load data even from corrupted or incompleted XML file.

```
preg_match_all('#<sd:id type="player">(.*?)</sd:id>#', $xml, $matches);
```

You have to have XML content in `$xml` and after this command you will have array of IDs in `$matches[1]` (so `$matches[1][0]` is first ID etc.).

If you need to parse XML properly and parse another tags than sd:id, try using XMLReader class, which is very fast and compatible with xml namespaces.